# React form hook - FormProvider not working

Tags: react-hook-form

I'm trying to use 'FormProvider' to connect the form to a child component input.
I created the exact same sample from the React-Form-Hook Docs and when trying to submit the form, it doesn't recognize the child component input. What I'm missing here?

Here is my code:[Sample Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-merkle-k8pje?file=/src/App.js:32-44)

Comment: on line number 6  ```const methods = useForm();``` do this. and consume register as ```useFormContext``` in the input component

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I created a connector component that consumes useFormContext and it wraps the input component and it still doesn't work

Comment: ParentComponent where you are using formprovider should consume useForm. and child component should consume useFormContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this in your parent component where using FormProvider

```
const methods = useForm();
<form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

inside InnerInput(Child)

```
const {register} = useFormContext
```